# AlertDialog is skippable. How avoid this?

Tags: android, dialog

I've started to create an android app (for myself, not for publish), and i've a little thing that I can't solve: when I show the AlertDialog, if I touch a point out it's window (that is grey area), the AlertDialog disappear without doing anything.

It's possible make AlertDialog not skippable? or when it disappear executes the code of the "cancel" button.
there is a screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY32e.png
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad;
```

Where you are showing alert dialog:

```
ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                final AlertDialog ab=ad.create();
                ad.setCancelable(false);
                ad.setMessage("YOUR_MESSAGE");
                ad.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ab.cancel();
                    }
                });
                ad.show();
```

Comment: thanks, all that I needed was this: ".setCancelable(false)"

Answer (score 0):

You can set cancelable false to allertdialog

```
    DialogFragment dialog= 
     MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance( R.string.alert_dialog_two_buttons_title);

     dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation
[Android Developer | setCanceledOnTouchOutside](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)

You can set whether a dialog is cancelable by outside touch using this method

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```